# Is it possible to reboot Live CD powered computer?

Tags: live-cd, live-usb, reboot

I'm now discovering Ubuntu 11.04 to check that its good with my hardware. I need to install some additional stuff and then make reboot. Problem is that I use Live CD (or is it called Live USB if its USB stick?) to "discover it".

Can I reboot it anyway?

Comment: Try installing ubuntu to a usb stick as per this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key

Comment: @fossfreedom That won't work for me. Any other way?

Comment: The problem with a liveCD or liveUSB is that it is not persistent - it doesnt remember what you have done.  Whilst you can install some stuff, it wont & cant remember it after a reboot.  That is why you need to install ubuntu to a usb stick to try these sorts of stuff.

Comment: Ye, I understand it. Anyway to simulate reboot? xD

Comment: Are you trying to modify the kernel (from your other question)?  You could try sudo modprobe -r <module> to unload before reloading with sudo modprobe <module>

Comment: Na, I'm not so smart. Just wanted easy way to test my hardware. Oka, nevermind. I guess there are no way to do it... without stick that's more then 4.4 gB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're talking about doing refers to having a persistent USB Drive. With what you currently are using yes, you can reboot it but no, you won't be able to save anything to it. An option have though is to make a LiveUSB that is able to be persistent, (Able to hold changes and save them, like saving a word document etc.) then you'd most likely be able to do what you're asking. To do this I recommend you use a USB Flash drive that has a minimum of 4GB of free memory, preferably 8GB if you have it. A (hopefully anyway) simple way to do this follows.

*Please Note: This tutorial is based for those with Windows Systems, and are trying out GNU/Linux on the aforementioned system.*

### What You Will Need

- The Universal USB Installer Program.
- A computer with an Internet Connection.
- A GNU/Linux ISO image. Ubuntu, Fedora, Kubuntu, Etc...

### What To Do

1. [DOWNLOAD](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or run the Universal USB Installer Program.
2. Browse and select your chosen GNU/Linux ISO Image. *NOTE: If you don't have one you will be given the option to download it before writing it to your chosen drive.*
3. Browse for and select your chosen USB Flash Drive.
4. **MAKE SURE** you have chosen the right flash/external drive **BEFORE** you write the ISO image to it as **ALL** data will be lost when this process is completed!!!
5. Write the ISO image to the flash drive, choosing if you wish to have a persistent storage and if so how much memory to allocate for said storage.
6. Restart your computer with the flash drive connected, boot to the flash drive, and enjoy your external USB Drive!
   Hope this helps you!

*P.S. If you need more info please do not hesitate to let me know...*

Answer (score 2):

[UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) allows you create LiveUSB for Ubuntu with persistence that allows you to save changes you make to the Live insatallation to the USB for use after reboot (persistence is only available for Ubuntu brand of Linux distributions as far as I'm aware of).

**Features:**

UNetbootin can create a bootable Live USB drive, or it can make a "frugal install" on your local hard disk if you don't have a USB drive. It loads distributions either by downloading a ISO (CD image) files for you, or by using an ISO file you've already downloaded.